# How do I select specific variables based on checkbox state as I iterate through a For Each

Tags: vb.net, variables, checkbox, foreach, selection

I'm working on a project that requires I iterate through a list of controls on a tabpage to find all of the checkboxes. Then depending on the state of the box (checked or unchecked) select individual variables (filenames) to then perform either a batch rename or delete of files on the filesystem (cb.checked = perform action).

I have managed to create the "for each" for the iteration of the controls (thanks google) but I'm struggling to figure out how to pick the variables. They are all named differently, obviously, as are the checkboxes. Also the checkboxes are statically assigned to the form/tabpage. Here's what I have at the moment.

```
Public Sub delBut_code(ByRef fname As String)
    If (Sanity = 1) Then
        For Each cb As Control In Form1.Controls
            If TypeOf cb Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(cb, 
                        CheckBox).Checked Then
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fname) Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(fname)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("All Actions Completed Successfully")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a File To Delete")
    End If
End Sub
```

and here is an example of some of the variables:

```
 Dim castle As String = selPath & "\zm_castle_loadingmovie.txt"
 Dim factory As String = selPath & 
         "\zm_factory_load_factoryloadingmovie.txt"
 Dim island As String = selPath & "\zm_island_loadingmovie.txt"
```

N.B selpath collects a user entered folder path and can be ignored here

I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The text says the checkboxes are on a tabpage, if so you wont find them in the form's controls collection.  If you know you have to do such a thing, it would be easier to create an array with those checkboxes and just iterate that.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can do much better with the loop:

```
Public Sub delBut_code(ByRef fname As String) 
    If Sanity <> 1 Then 
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a File To Delete")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim checked = Form1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().Where(Function(c) c.Checked)
    For Each box As CheckBox in checked
        Try  
           'A file not existing is only one reason among many this could fail, 
            ' so it needs to be in a Try/Catch block.
            ' And once you're using a Try/Catch block anyway,
            ' the FileExists() check becomes a slow and unnecessary extra trip to the disk.
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(fname)
        Catch
           'Do something here to let the user know it failed for this file
        End Try
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("All Actions Completed")
End Sub
```

But now you need to know how have the right value in that `fname` variable. There's not enough information in the question for us to fully answer this, but we can give some suggestions. There a number of ways you could do this:

- Set the [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the Checkboxes when you build the string variables. Then `fname` becomes `DirectCast(box.Tag, String)`.
- Inherit a custom control from CheckBox to use instead of a normal Checkbox that has an additional String property for the file name. Set this property when you build the string variables.
- Name your string variables in a way that you can derive the string variable name from the CheckBox variable name, and then use a `Switch` to pick the right string variable from each `box.Name`.
- Keep a `Dictionary(Of CheckBox, String)` that maps the Checkboxes to the right string values.

But without knowing more context of the application, I hesitate to recommend any of these over the others as best for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. honestly i thought i'd covered all the required info but i was also a little sleep deprived.  I think probably the dictionary method would be better. The problem is the file paths will be user defined as they will potentially be different for every machine it is run on but the filenames will be the same as they are a static property. The paths are stored in the registry and i do have some code to detect it but i also have a textbox on each tabpage so the user can change it if the detection screws up. Is that detection code going to be an issue?

Comment: Just sat down and typed out some code. After a quick browse of MSDN I ended up using the tag property (i like simple code). Thanks again.